# Why does the Identify message find an actor in an actor selection after its termination?

Tags: scala, akka

Within a test-program, I want to check that an Actor (`child`) remains terminated and is not created again after some computation. My test looks like (it is part of a TestKit subclass):

```
val childSelection = system.actorSelection(parent.path / "*")
childSelection ! Identify(0)
val child = expectMsgPF {
  case ActorIdentity(0, Some(ref)) => ref
}
watch(child)
// some computation that should end in stopping child
expectTermiated(child)
// some computation that should not create a new child
childSelection ! Identify(1)
expectMsg(ActorIdentity(1, None))
```

The last line sometimes unexpectedly fails, stating that the message ActorIdentity(1, Some(*parent.path/child-name*)) was received instead of the expected one. This means that, even after receiving the Terminated message (resulting from the `expectTerminated(...)` test), sending the Identify message to an actor selection does not necessarily result in the ActorIdentity(..., None) response.

Does anybody know what the akka framework actually does and how it works in this case? Thanks in advance for your help!

Meanwhile, I replaced the last line of my test with:

```
val identities = receiveWhile() {
  case ActorIdentity(1, Some(ref)) => ref == child
}
if (identities.isEmpty) {
  expectMsg(ActorIdentity(1, None))
} else {
  expectNoMsg
}
```

which seems to work fine but is quite more complex to read (and write)...

Comment: did you try graceful shutdown of the actor as in docs http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html#Graceful_Stop

Comment: no, the child stops itself using context.stop(self). The Terminated message sent to my test-program should attest that the child is actually stopped. However, it seems that the child, even stopped, remains "visible" on the akka platform for a short time...

Answer (score 0):

Since you selection is on `parent.path / "*"`, your `parent` actor probably have another child that is responding to the `Identity` message. Check what identity your receive after stopping the child, to figure out what other child is responding.

Comment: The received identity is exactly the one of the child... Hence my question!

Comment: How is the child stopped ? Can you share a full test case that reproduces the issue ?